# Shopify theme top menu issue, can't get it to fit on one line

Tags: html, css, shopify

Here's the site:
http://sawsafetystore-com.myshopify.com/

You can see the menu at the top (Home, Chain Saw Safety, etc.).  No matter how much I tinker with the CSS, I cannot get it to fit on one line.

I've changed the padding, font-size, etc.  Even though you can clearly see that it SHOULD fit on one line now, or at least one more item, I just can't get it to.

Is there some tag or property I am missing somewhere?  I've tinkered with the element `#main-nav li a` element's font-size, margins, padding, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Posting problematic code is the best way to garner troubleshooters, not links to sites. We want the fish without going fishing. Throw some code up and I would be happy to help.

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't find the problematic code in the CSS otherwise I would have for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS

c6-screen.css --> line number 94

```
#main-nav {
font-size: 12px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked great, just one more question, how do I center the elements (home, chain saw, etc.)  anywhere I put `text-align:center` doesn't work!

Comment: @Tom set #main-nav li a { padding: 7px 18px 5px 18px; } c6-screen.css --> line number 96

Comment: what I have on that line is `{ padding: 7px 36px 5px 0px; font-size: 16px;  line-height: 35px; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; color: #999999; display: inline-block;  border: 6px solid transparent; border-width: 6px 0;}` and if I add `text-align:center;` nothing happens.  No big deal I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The #main-nav has a set width of 745px. (base.css, line 131)
Remove or override this and it will fit on one line